# F# XML type provider changes name

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data

Using the XML type provider in FSharp.Data (Version 2.0.5) the element names don't match the names in the schema.

For example my XML files starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebQuery><Results><Result><PrimaryID>105882365</PrimaryID><CONTACT_ADDRESS_LINE_1 /><CONTACT_ADDRESS_LINE_2 />
```

but in F# I need to reference CONTACT_ADDRESS_LINE_1 with

```
.ContactAddressLine1
```

Is there something about type providers I don't understand? Why is the name in F# different from the element name in the schema?

Comment: `CONTACT_ADDRESS_LINE_1` seems so jarring considering the format the other elements follow.

Comment: ChaosPandoin - Perhaps so, but I don't control the schema, it is what is provided by an outside firm.

Comment: I'll have to do some reading up on the XML type provider. I can't help but wonder whether they keep internal metadata on the element that represents the original form. It seems possible that they might format names to a more .NET convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# Data makes property names PascalCased for readability, but that has zero impact on the functionality, by using ContactAddressLine1 you'll still be accessing the CONTACT_ADDRESS_LINE_1 element

Comment: Actually this does affect functionality since XML element (and attribute) names are case-sensitive, so “location” and “Location” refer to different elements and it would be possible to have both in the same schema.

Comment: In that case one property would be called Location and the other Location2. Don't worry, the actual attribute and element names don't need to match the generated properties. If you want you can decompile the generated executable to see that it's using the right names

Comment: Gustavo - I accept your answer that this is by design. I don't like the design but this isn't the place for that discussion. Thank you.

Comment: Consider to contribute a static parameter which disables the current naming. Most people actually like it.